# Shrinking NTFS drive doesnot allow all free space of the disk to be used

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGHu.png) is what my current partition looks like. I tried to shrink the `D:` drive to create another new `ext4` drive, but the problem is, even though it has 39GB free, only 6GB is allowed to be shrinked. ([Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnu2n.png)).
The page file is located on `C:` drive, not on `D:`.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Why not use GParted? It will do everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally just means there's data in the way of the shrinking. All of your data doesn't exist at the start of the partition, so it can only be shrunk to where the last piece of data is in the partition.

Defragmenting the partition should help.

EDIT: In the case that defragmenting does not help, here are some other suggestions I found here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/

> ```
> Run the Disk Cleanup Wizard, making sure to remove the hibernation file and all restore points.
> Disable System Restore
> Disable the pagefile ( Open up System in Control Panel, then Advanced System Settings \ Advanced \ Performance \ Advanced \ Change
> ```
>
> \ No Paging File.
>       In the same Advanced Settings, go to Startup and Recovery \ Settings and then change the Write debugging information drop-down to
>   “None” to disable the kernel memory dump.
>       Disable Hibernation mode in your power options \ advanced power options screen.
>       Reboot the machine, and then delete your c:\pagefile.sys file, following these instructions if you are having issues.

Sounds like there may be files at the end of the partition which are immovable, such as the Master File Table.

Supposedly a free trial of [Perfect Disk](http://www.raxco.com/home/products/perfectdisk-pro) should be able to move it.

Comment: Nope it does not.

Comment: Added some more suggestions from HowToGeek

Comment: @DamodarDahal - Yes;  It should.  The information warning message in your very own screenshot explains whats going on.  One way to confirm this fact, remove all data on the partition, that should allow you to shrink the volume.

Comment: oh sorry it actually **works** if completely defragmented. Thanx buddy. :D